# Putting mutiple booleans into an unsigned char?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

Currently I'm working on an NES emulator and I'm working on the CPU core.  I've searched all over the internet, but I can't find the right keywords find the answer to my question, so I thought I'd ask it here.  What I have is seven booleans that act as my processor status flags.  The current opcode I'm working on wants me to push the processor status flags to the stack.  My stack is of the unsigned char datatype.  I thought I would be able to smash the booleans together like this:

```
bool C, Z, I, D, B, V, N;
unsigned char example;

example = {C, Z, I, D, B, V, N, 0};
```

That didn't work, so how do I go about putting all of my boolean processor status flags into an unsigned char datatype so I can push the flags onto my stack?

Comment: Have you considered using bit fields in some way?

Answer (score 3):

```
enum { C=0x01, Z=0x02, I=0x04, D=0x08,
       B=0x10, V=0x20, N=0x40 };
unsigned char flags = 0;
```

This works because only one bit is set in each constant. To determine whether the flag is set, use `(flags & FLAGNAME)` like `(flags & C)` to determine if it is set. Be careful not to get the bitwise AND (&) I used confused with the Boolean/logical AND (&&). The && operator won't work in place of the & operator. To set a flag, use `(flags |= FLAGNAME)` and to unset it, use `flags &= ~FLAGNAME;`. Adjust the constants for the correct order, so the NES instruction can properly check the flags. After all, if they're not in the correct order, the wrong flag values may be used, which obviously would be a problem.

Also, don't forget the parentheses. The bitwise operators have very low precedence, so parentheses around the expression are essential.

If you don't know about the bitwise operators, they are worth reading up on.

**Edit**

A handy set of macros for you:

```
#define FLAG_ISSET(x) (flags & (x))
#define FLAG_SET(x) (flags |= (x))
#define FLAG_CLEAR(x) (flags &= ~(x))

...
if (FLAG_ISSET(C))
  ...

FLAG_SET(V);
FLAG_CLEAR(Z);
```

Comment: Except that in C++, those should be inline functions (probably with two parameters).

Comment: Maybe, though personally I would prefer macros in this case. CPU flags are constantly modified, so I'd imagine the flags register and its associated values to be global unless they're in a class. Either way, only one function parameter in necessary. The inline function would have the benefit of type checking, but there should be no reason to do type checking since the flag constants should be used anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try `std::bitset`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset I couldn't find a way to construct it using initializer lists, but you can always use the `operator[]` or `set()` to set each bit, and use `to_ulong()` to convert it to a number (then you can convert the unsigned long to an unsigned char trivially).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   bitset<7> reg;
   bool C = true, Z = false, I = false, D = false, B = true, V = true, N = false;

   reg[6] = C;
   reg[5] = Z;
   reg[4] = I;
   reg[3] = D;
   reg[2] = B;
   reg[1] = V;
   reg[0] = N;

   unsigned char example = static_cast<unsigned char>(reg.to_ulong());
   printf("0x%x\n", example);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I gave this a try, and with all booleans set I get 97 as my output, when I should be getting 127.

Comment: Then you probably did something wrong. I ran this program with all variables set to true, and the output was 0x7f, which is exactly 127 (with a g++ 4.7.2 compiler).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
bool C, Z, I, D, B, V, N;
unsigned char example = 0;

if(C)
   example |= (1 << 7)
if(Z)
   example |= (1 << 6)
if(I)
   example |= (1 << 5)
if(D)
   example |= (1 << 4)
if(B)
   example |= (1 << 3)
if(V)
   example |= (1 << 2)
if(N)
   example |= (1 << 1)
```

Comment: This is what I'm going to use I think.  I can't believe I didn't think of this myself.

Comment: This doesn't work for some reason.  I'm testing this in a separate program with cout << (int)example << endl; and the output is whatever the last bit that was OR'd in.  For example, if N is set, then the output is 1.  If only C is set, then the output is 128.

Comment: makes sense. byte (or bit mask) 10000000 (equal to only C is set) is the same as the decimal value 128.

Comment: I typed that out wrong.  If all bool values are set, then the output is 128.  If every bit but the 7th bit is set, then the output is 64.  For some reason, the output is whatever the highest set bit is, and the other bits below it are ignored.

Comment: hmm. I am not quite sure if this will work, but have you tried printf("%u", example);
instead of cout << (int)example;
. I suspect the error may be caused by the integer casting.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit heavy to be putting in an emulator, but why not convert each boolean value into a bit in the character, then decode the character once you need to pull it off your stack.

```
unsigned char encodeBits(bool bools[8]) {
    unsigned char retval = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        retval += (bools[i] ? 1 : 0);
        retval = (i < 7 ? retval << 1 : retval);
    }

    return retval;
}
```

This code basically just shifts the boolean value into a character.

Then to decode, pass an empty array by reference,

```
void decodeBits(bool (&bools)[8], unsigned char input) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        bools[i] = (input & 0x00000001 ? true : false);
        input = (i < 7 ? input >> 1 : input);
    }
}
```

This code should compare the first bit of the character, then shift it etc. etc.

This can be done without arrays but for simplicity's sake I used arrays.

Edit: A working example: http://ideone.com/hQ47nn

Comment: This works great.  The output array comes out in reverse order for me, but that's no problem.  Thank you!

Comment: There are ways of getting around that backwards issue, but if it works backwards there is no need to incur any more overhead by reversing the order of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `int status` is your CPU status register.
You could create some defines like these:

```
#define CPU_REG_STATUS_C 0x00000040
#define CPU_REG_STATUS_Z 0x00000020
#define CPU_REG_STATUS_I 0x00000010
#define CPU_REG_STATUS_D 0x00000008
#define CPU_REG_STATUS_B 0x00000004
#define CPU_REG_STATUS_V 0x00000002
#define CPU_REG_STATUS_N 0x00000001
```

and then set/unset the flags indipendently from each other by using the bitwise binary operators & and |

example1: setting the ZERO flag

```
status |= CPU_REG_STATUS_Z;
```

example2: checking the value of the ZERO flag:

```
if(status & CPU_REG_STATUS_Z)
{
   //zero flag is set
}
else
{
   //zero flag is unset
}
```

however, there are plenty of CPU core source codes out there, especially for the 6502 CPU (Commodore C64, Nintendo NES and many others) so you have to bother only with the emulation of the console.

http://www.6502.org/tools/emu/

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
bool C, Z, I, D, B, V, N;
unsigned char example = 0;
const unsigned char mask = 0x01;

if(N)
   example |= mask << 1;
if(V)
   example |= mask << 2;
//...   
if(C)
   example |= mask << 7;
```